# php/sql/html: Data dont show in the option field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm sorry if this question may sound stupid, but i have one problem with my code that i don't know how solve even though i think it really easy for other people.
I'm making some form when user enter their info (example: username) then the output will shown in the option field (example:responsibility). For your information every username have many responsibility.
The problem is the output is creating many option field and not only one.

below is my php code that related with option field:

```
<?php
// 3.php is my config file

require("3.php");

$link = mysqli_connect($h,$u,$p,$db);
//if ($link)
//echo "Connection OK";
//else echo "connection failed";

$q = $_GET['q'];
$query="SELECT resp_name FROM view_ss_user_responsibility WHERE user_name ='".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query)
or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

$fn=$row[0];

echo "<br>";
//echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
echo "<tr><td>Responsibility:</td>
<td align=center><form><select><option value='$row[0]'>$fn</option></select></form></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

And also this is the output (i'm using ajax, so no submit button)
[image]

if you want to see my html/javascript file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function showResult(str) {
 if (str.length==0) {
     document.getElementById("search").innerHTML="";
     document.getElementById("search").style.border="0px";
     return;
 }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("search").innerHTML=this.responseText;
        document.getElementById("search").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
   }
 }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","2.php?q="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form>
 username &nbsp;<input type="text" size="30" name ='pass' onkeyup="showResult(this.value)"><br>
<div id="search"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

so, base from this i hope someone can tell me on how to do it, thank you.

(why is this getting downvote?.its not like i'm forcing you all to answer it)

Comment: That's because the code is in a loop: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){`  If you only want one, then only use whichever record you want instead of looping over every record.  (Though if you only want one then why is it a drop down list?)

Comment: @David i don't want only one. I make the output as the option for the user to choose  which responsibility they want. (this code i use for login page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will work fine..

**Change this to:**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    $fn = $row[0];

    echo "<br>";
//echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<tr><td>Responsibility:</td>
<td align=center><form><select><option value='$row[0]'>$fn</option></select></form></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**This:**

```
echo "<table><tr><td>Responsibility:</td><td><select>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    $fn = $row[0];
    echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$fn</option>";
}
echo "</select></td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: Thanks you, it work. but can you  tell me what's wrong with my code.

Comment: The problem was in while loop you have to just iterate options because you want multiple `options` instead of multiple other tags and one more thing you haven't added opening of `table` tag